# Открытие следующего окна из другого файла.py в CustomTkinter используя ООП

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter, gui, customtkinter

Для понимания ситуации. Хочу сделать так, чтобы каждое открываемое окно было в отдельном файле (мне кажется так гораздо удобнее работать с ними, когда приложение разрастется).

Посмотрел очень много видео на эту тему, прочитал парочку статей, но никак не могу понять как это сделать на моем примере.

Если я использую не то `GUI` для этого, напишите пожалуйста какое лучше подойдет для моих целей.

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, открывалось другое окно из другого файла **settings.py**. 
Когда запускаю мой код **main.py**, открываются сразу оба окна и кнопка перехода на следующую страницу не работает.

**main.py**:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from configuration_for_page import Settings


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('main')
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="settings", command=self.next_page())
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)

    def next_page(self):
        Settings(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

**settings.py**:

```
import customtkinter as ctk


class Settings(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title('settings')
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.resizable(False, False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`CustomTkinter`** — это библиотека пользовательского интерфейса *Python*, основанная на *Tkinter*, которая предоставляет новые, современные и полностью настраиваемые виджеты.

Они создаются и используются как обычные виджеты *Tkinter*, а также могут использоваться в сочетании с обычными элементами *Tkinter*. 
Виджеты и цвета окон либо адаптируются к внешнему виду системы, либо к установленному вручную режиму ('light', 'dark'), а все виджеты и окна `CustomTkinter` поддерживают масштабирование *HighDPI (Windows, macOS)*. 
С `CustomTkinter` вы получите единообразный и современный вид на всех настольных платформах (*Windows*, *macOS*, *Linux*).

**q1542010_main.py**

```
import customtkinter as ctk                    # pip install customtkinter

#from configuration_for_page import Settings
#--> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <----> vvvvvvvvvvvvvv <----<----<----<----<----<----<----
from q1542010_settings import ToplevelWindow                 

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Main')
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.resizable(False, False)

#       self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="settings", command=self.next_page())
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------???-> ^^ <-???

        self.button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(
            self, 
            text="Open CTkToplevel", 
            command=self.open_toplevel
        )
        self.button_1.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)
        self.button_2 = ctk.CTkButton(
            self, 
            text="set light", 
            command=lambda: ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")
        )
        self.button_2.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)

        self.toplevel_window = None
        
    def open_toplevel(self):
        if self.toplevel_window is None:  # создавать окно верхнего уровня, только если оно еще не открыто
            self.toplevel_window = ToplevelWindow(
                self, 
                closing_event=self.toplevel_close_event
            )

    def toplevel_close_event(self):
        self.toplevel_window = None
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

**q1542010_settings.py**

```
import customtkinter as ctk


class ToplevelWindow(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, closing_event=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closing)
        self.geometry("600x300")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.closing_event = closing_event

        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="ToplevelWindow")
        self.label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(
            self, 
            text="set dark", 
            command=lambda: ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        )
        self.button_1.pack(side="top", padx=40, pady=40)

    def closing(self):
        self.destroy()
        if self.closing_event is not None:
            self.closing_event()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @kavo что не так?

Comment: Вступление выглядит как скопированное откуда-то или сгенерированное с помощью ChatGPT. В принципе, не понятно, зачем оно добавлено и как отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @insolor это ваше личное мнение и вы имеете право на него.

Comment: И все это есть в документации по Tkinter? Что такое closing_event?

Comment: @kavo все это есть в  https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter

Comment: @S. Nick спасибо

Comment: @kavo пожалуйста